# ProGuard usage on an application that uses Object Serialization

Tags: java, proguard, serializable

I have an application that uses a SaveData class, which uses ObjectOutputStream to save serialized data, and a LoadData class, which uses an ObjectInputStream to load the data. I have tried looking here, http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/examples.html , for help, but something just doesn't make sense. They are using `private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);` in the place of `void writeObject(java.lang.Object);` and `private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);` instead of `public Object readObject();`. What is that about? Also, why would I need to include such methods? I have a Data class that has a `private static final long serialVersionUID`. Should I just simply 
`-keepclassmembers Data implements java.io.Serializable {
   static final long serialVersionUID;
}` ?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html). More specifically, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/output.html#861).

Comment: So, the signature is NOT how you would use it in the `.java` files? Even though, you would say something like `myObject = oostream.readObject();` where `oostream` is an `ObjectOutputStream`? Or is this a very different readObject, writeObject that I don't usually deal with (and possibly some behind-the-scenes stuff for ANY Class that implements java.io.Serializable)?

Comment: The `readObject` and `writeObject` methods are used internally by the `ObjectOutputStream`, you should never invoke them directly, hence why they're `private`. They allow you to create your own custom serialization format instead of (or in addition to) using the default one provided by `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: So, even if `Data` just had a serialVersionUID, get, and set methods, you would still have to include the signatures of `readObject`, `writeObject`, and other serialization methods?

Comment: No, `ObjectOutputStream` just uses the default method if they're not specified (see [`ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#defaultWriteObject()) for the default). The only way an error can occur with serializing objects is if it tries to serialize something that isn't `Serializable`.